# Android Navigation Drawer Error Using With Recycler View

Tags: android, json, navigation-drawer, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to prepare dynamic navigation drawer. I'm using RecylerView. My Codes Are Here :

Listele.java

```
package com.example.hp.myapplication;

/**
* Created by hp on 25.7.2016.
*/

public class Listele {

private String adi;
private String resim;

public Listele(String adi, String resim) {
    this.adi = adi;
    this.resim = resim;
}

public String getAdi() {
    return adi;
}

public void setAdi(String adi) {
    this.adi = adi;
}

public String getResim() {
    return resim;
}

public void setResim(String resim) {
    this.resim = resim;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Listele{" +
            "adi='" + adi + '\'' +
            ", resim='" + resim + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

ListeleAdapter.java

```
package com.example.hp.myapplication;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
* Created by hp on 25.7.2016.
*/

public class ListeleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListeleAdapter.urunlistem> {

private Context contexto;
private ArrayList<Listele>tortica;

public ListeleAdapter(Context contexto, ArrayList<Listele> tortica) {
    this.contexto = contexto;
    this.tortica = tortica;

}

@Override

public urunlistem onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new urunlistem(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()) .inflate(R.layout.list,null));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(urunlistem holder, int position) {

    holder.adi.setText(tortica.get(position).getAdi());
            Glide.with(contexto).load("http://192.168.1.33:8080/urunler/"+tortica.get(position).getResim()).into(holder.tresim);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return tortica.size();
}

public class urunlistem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView tresim;
    TextView adi;


    public urunlistem(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);





        tresim=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.resim);
        adi=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.adi);


    }


}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.hp.myapplication;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private static final String     url="http://192.168.1.33:8080/urunler/goruntule2.php";
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ListeleAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<Listele> listeles = new ArrayList<>();
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
RequestQueue requestQu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    requestQu = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    goster();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private void goster() {

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Bilgiler alınıyor");
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listado);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter = new ListeleAdapter(this, listeles);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++)
            {

                try {
                    JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    String resimurl=object.getString("resim");
                    String adi=object.getString("adi");

                    listeles.add(new Listele(adi,resimurl));


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    requestQu.add(request);



}
}
```

**EDIT:**
It gives and error  like

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   com.example.hp.myapplication, PID: 7960 java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.hp.myapplication/com.example.hp.myapplication.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.example.hp.myapplication.MainActivity.goster(MainActivity.java:123)
>   at
>   com.example.hp.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  D/dalvikvm:
>   GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 378K, 13% free 3267K/3716K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
>
> ```
>     [ 08-14 17:13:15.298    77:   77 D/         ]
>     Socket deconnection
>
>     [ 08-14 17:13:17.294    77:   77 D/         ]
>     Socket deconnection
>
>     [ 08-14 17:13:19.302    77:   77 D/         ]
>     Socket deconnection
>
>     [ 08-14 17:13:21.298    77:   77 D/         ]
>     Socket deconnection
>
>     [ 08-14 17:13:23.298    77:   77 D/         ]
>     Socket deconnection
>
>     [ 08-14 17:13:25.298    77:   77 D/         ]
>     Socket deconnection
>
>     [ 08-14 17:13:27.298    77:   77 D/         ]
>     Socket deconnection
>
>     [ 08-14 17:13:29.302    77:   77 D/         ]
>     Socket deconnection
>
>     [ 08-14 17:13:31.310    77:   77 D/         ]
>     Socket deconnection Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8615', transport: 'socket'
> ```

Comment: can you post full log pls?

Comment: first check if there is a view in activity_main.xml whose id is fab. then change new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,.. to new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this,...